# Collectors.groupingBy and map

Tags: java, java-8

I'm struggling to `groupBy` name all the persons after a calculation with Doubles.

```
persons.stream()
                .map(p -> (p.getHeight() * p.getWeight()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName)));
```

but `Stream<Double>` is not applicable for these arguments.

How can I process integers/ doubles and then groupBy String?

Comment: @Todd has answered why you are seeing this problem, but it will help to say what you are trying to accomplish or what you want your results to be.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to show results of calculations without the name of each group. I was hoping to find a way by using cast or reduce but it's OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution would be as follows:

```
 persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
   Person::getName,
   HashMap::new,
   Collectors.mapping(
      p -> p.getHeight() * p.getWeight()
      Collectors.toList())));
```

Or, if you don't expect duplicate names, you can use the much simpler

```
persons.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
   Person::getName,
   p -> p.getHeight() * p.getWeight()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because your `map` is mapping it from `Person` to `Integer` or `Double`, (depending on how height/weight are measured). Once the `map` call is done, you effectively have a stream of numbers so you can't collect them as `Person` objects.

```
persons.stream() // Stream of Person objects
  .map(p -> (p.getHeight() * p.getWeight())) // Stream of numbers.
```

And the JavaDoc for Stream.map() confirms this:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

Maybe if we knew more about what you were trying to do with the streams, we could give you a more direct answer on how to solve the problem.